# Why does Yalkut Yosef recommend women not do "tashlich"?

Tags: minhag, women, rosh-hashanah-new-year, tashlich

I read in Yalkut Yossef that women don't need to go to Tashlikh and the Rav Y. Yossef shlit"a concludes with "Shev Veal Tasse Adif" (trans. it's better to do nothing).

Does anyone know the reason ? I read that in the Kitsur but the Rav doesn't develop.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Aruch haShulchan 583:4 says that woman should not go where the men go for Tashlich. http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9102&st=&pgnum=284
I would imagine that the reason is in order to avoid mingling.

Comment: which today is a widespread problem

Comment: He also doesn't seem to recommend anyone does Tashlich at all.

Comment: Thanks Gershon. I get access to the full Yalkut Yossef and there is a reference to the Mate Ephrayim. The reason is the one your give.